# How to type =|| = in MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to type the following symbol (for logical equivalence):
[image]

Some editors have the command `\DashvDash` available, but SE's MathJax doesn't.
Alternatively, the symbol can be defined via `\reflectbox{\vDash}\!\vDash`, but this requires the package `graphicx` which isn't included either.

How can I render the above symbol in SE's MathJax?

Comment: Doesn't $\equiv$ suffice?  `\equiv`

Comment: No, some sources reserve $\equiv$ for syntactic identity (and I also prefer the analogy to $\vDash$ over a completely different looking symbol).

Answer (score 7):

The commands `\DashvDash` and `\dashVdash` in LaTeX are part of the stix package. As far as I can tell, they are not available in MathJax. However, you could use Unicode. (These symbols can be found in the Unicode block [Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Mathematical_Symbols-A).) Or you could simply copy-paste them when needed.

- `$⟛$` and `$⟚$` produces $⟛$ and $⟚$
- `$\unicode{x27DA}$` and `$\unicode{x27DB}$` produced $\unicode{x27DA}$ and $\unicode{x27DB}$

You might also use \mathrel to get the required spacing. (In the stix package in LaTeX, this is a relation symbol.) Compare $x \mathrel{⟛} y$ and $x ⟛ y$. (Obtained by `$x \mathrel{⟛} y$` and `$x ⟛ y$`.)

If you have a post where you use this symbol often, you might want to create a shortcut. For example, after including `$\newcommand{\DvD}{\mathrel{\unicode{x27DB}}}$` you can then simply use in the post `\DvD` whenever you need this command. (I have avoided using the standard name from the stix package on purpose - it seems better not to redefine standard macros. We do not know whether these commands might be implemented in MathJax at some point in the future.)

Example: $\newcommand{\DvD}{\mathrel{\unicode{x27DB}}}\DvD$.

I would have included some examples similar to the actual usage of this symbol - but I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 4):

How does $=\hspace{-5pt}|\hspace{-.5pt}|\hspace{-5pt}=$ look?

Comment: Neat! Combining with Martin Sleziak's answer to make it a relation, this can be defined as a new command at the start of a post, to save excess typing: `$\newcommand{DashvDash}{\mathrel{=\hspace{-5pt}|\hspace{-.5pt}|\hspace{-5pt}=}}$` So defining silently: $\newcommand{DashvDash}{\mathrel{=\hspace{-5pt}|\hspace{-.5pt}|\hspace{-5pt}=}}$, and using it here: $a\DashvDash b$.